# Derivative of a Point(x,y) wrt symbol 'x' in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a Point defined in Sympy let's say Point(x,y). If I take the derivative of the Point(x,y) wrt 'x', it should return 'y' I guess. But it returns something else.

Here is the code

```
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy.abc import x, y
p3 = Point(x,y)
diff(p3,x)
```

The output is

```
Derivative(Point2D(x, y), x)
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I have never heard about the derivative of a point. What is the function you are trying to express. Write in standard mathematical notation